# Installation of SONARQUBE on Ubuntu / Debian

Tags: ubuntu, sonarqube

I'm trying to install SONARQUBE (http://www.sonarqube.org/) on Ubuntu.

- downloaded + extracted the ZIP-File
- installed mysql-server and added the database for sonar
- modified the sonar.properties file as described in http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing
- started the server by calling "sh /sonar.sh start" -> "Started SonarQube"

It seems that the server starts up but terminates few seconds later, because when i call "sonar.sh stop" it says, that the server was not running.

Any suggestions what the problem could be?

Comment: Could you show us the logs ? (located in `$SONAR_HOME/logs/sonar.log`)

Comment: I ananlyzed the logs. There was a problem with the database connection so the server started and shutdown after few seconds. I fixed that and now the last log entry are: 2014.10.23 09:56:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Logging]  Web server is started
2014.10.23 09:56:04 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up. When i try to access the website via localhost:9000 there is no error output anymore but there is no content in the HTML sourcecode (page keeps beeing blank)!

Comment: You should paste the whole sonar.log content here or somewhere else, because there must definitely be some error in the middle of the startup.

Comment: Finally got it to work. You're right, there was an error in the Startup process, i watched at the wrong logfile... Thanks for your help!